# Retrieve all values of an indexed variable in Mongodb without iterating over all records

Tags: mongodb

I have a large MongoDB database consisting of millions of records. I want to retrieve all values for a variable which has an index associated with it. Is there a method to retrieve all values for this indexed variable which is faster than iterating over all records?

Comment: add you query and document sample

Comment: How many different values can it have?  Could you use the Aggregation framework's $group operator or a Map-Reduce job to calculate the unique values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you writing query in mongo it use own query analyser which will use optimal indexes for the query.

For considering which index will use by the analyser add `.explain()` at the end of the query.